# Debugging problems that arise from corrupt threads in Visual Studio 2012 (or later) for c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, stack-corruption

While this topic may sound broad, I could find little to no information online on this subject.

Basically, my application works normally until some random amount of time passes - then it crashes. I've managed to debug only that it happens in some **Win64 Thread** with a single stack frame. I have all windows debugging symbols loaded but it doesn't even show anything in the disassembly view, just and endless stream of

```
00007FF8CE9F2890  ?? ??
00007FF8CE9F2891  ?? ?? 
00007FF8CE9F2892  ?? ?? 
00007FF8CE9F2893  ?? ?? 
00007FF8CE9F2894  ?? ??
```

I've looked at all the other threads and I could not find anything out of the ordinary, nor do i know which thread created the Win64 thread (it spawns later, I can't pinpoint when).

According to this post
[How to know who is the parent thread of a given thread ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950082/how-to-know-who-is-the-parent-thread-of-a-given-thread-id)

it's not even possible to find out and apparently there's no tracking system built into the VS IDE?

So what can I do in this situation? What are some good methods to get to the bottom of such problems?

Comment: You need some more sophisticated tool for this. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: @SergeyA thanks for the useful link but the problem is that I can't even comprehend the type of error that's causing this. It's a long list so I'll keep looking but none of it seems like the obvious go-to tool for this kind of problem :/